# Getting date value from an array hash

Tags: ruby, date, hash, tags

I have a hash that looks like

```
tagArray = { :"2014Date"=>["11/22/2014"], :"2015Date"=>["03/21/2015"] }
```

Since i already know for a given key, there is only one element in the array of 'values', how can you get just the value not as an array?

```
value = tagArray[:"2015Date"]
=>
value = ["04/12/2015"]
```

You can just index the array then and get the date like

```
value = value.fetch(0).to_s
=>
value = "04/12/2015"
```

However I am looking for a more elegant way of doing it.

Note: I am using Ruby 2.2, so need to 'strp' the date first to change it from mm/dd/yyyy format which is the end goal.

Comment: Why are you using an array if there can be only one value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit simpler:

```
 value = tagArray[:"2015Date"].last
 => 
 value = "03/21/2015"
```